# Issue between UiaComWrapper and UIAutomation AutomationElement

Tags: coded-ui-tests, uiautomation

Both UiaComWrapper and UIAutomationTypes contain 'AutomationElement' class and its related properties. UiaComWrapper is added by default for every CodedUI project.

How can I change UiaComWrapper 'AutomationElement' to UIAutomationTypes 'AutomationElement'?